# How can I see the results of modifying variable ibuffer-saved-filter-groups without restarting Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I'm trying to modify the alist ibuffer-saved-filter-groups. But after I quit ibuffer and eval the setq statement, the ibuffer categories don't change when I run M-x ibuffer. The changes only get reflected when I restart emacs completely.

i.e. Modifying this list, requires an emacs complete restart to take effect:

```
(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
  (quote (("default"
            ("Org" ;; all org-related buffers
         (mode . org-mode)
         (mode . ruby-mode))
            ("Mail"
              (or  ;; mail-related buffers
               (mode . message-mode)
               (mode . mail-mode)
               ;; etc.; all your mail related modes
               ))
            ("Emacs"
              (or
                (mode . emacs-lisp-mode)
                ))
        ("Scratch"
              (or
                (mode . lisp-interaction-mode)
                ))
            ("ERC"   (mode . erc-mode))
        ("Consoles" 
         (mode . term-mode))
        ("Help" (or (name . "\*Help\*")
             (name . "\*Apropos\*")
             (name . "\*info\*")
             (name . "\*Compile-Log\*")
             (name . "\*Backtrace\*")
             (name . "\*Messages\*")))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either kill the `*Ibuffer*` buffer or choose which filter group to use:

```
M-x ibuffer
/ R "default"
```